# Using a data disk

Tags: filesystems, mount, disk

I have a separate disk that i'd like to use for data.

```
[~] » lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0     1M  0 part
├─sda2   8:2    0   260M  0 part /boot
├─sda3   8:3    0   200G  0 part /
└─sda4   8:4    0 265.5G  0 part /home
sdb      8:16   0 149.1G  0 disk
└─sdb1   8:17   0 149.1G  0 part
[~] »
```

I want to mount it on `$HOME/data`, but i don't want to need root permissions for it.
Since `/home/$USER` is automatically mounted on boot and my user doesn't require root to use it, maybe i can use the same mount options for mounting the data disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an entry for `/home/.../data` to `/etc/fstab`. You can use the same mount options as for `/home`.

After the volume has been mounted you have to execute `chown $username: /home/$username/data` once (as `root`).